# Python multiple if/elif/else statements and display only user selections

Tags: python

using python 2.7.5, solving programming class problem where order total is added to a shipping cost, prices are set for shipping to US and Canada, I have code written for shipping to US but need to change the values so if the user selects canada a different set of values are applied to the order total. 
Canada shipping is: 8.00 for less than 50.0, 12.0 for more than 50.01 - 100.0, 15.0 for 100.01 - 150.0, I need a way to replace these values with the US shipping ones in the code below:

```
user_order = float(input("how much is your order? "))
user_ship_area = raw_input('Are you shipping to the US or Canada?')

if user_order < 50.00 and user_ship_area == "US": #start selection with user order and shipping area. 
    #User would be given price for shipping according to order cost   
    print 'you must pay $6.00 for shipping ' #user order less than 50$ = 64 for shipping.
    user_order = user_order + 6.0

elif user_order < 100.0 > 50.01 and user_ship_area == "US": #must include range of numbers, if user order is over 50.01 but under 100.0 
    print 'you must pay $9.00 for shipping'   #they must pay 9.00 for shipping.
    user_order = user_order + 9.0

elif user_order < 150.0 > 100.01 and user_ship_area == "US": #if user order is over 100.01$ but under 150$ 
    print 'you must pay $12.00 for shipping '#12.00$ will be charged for shipping
    user_order = user_order + 12.0 
else: 
    print 'congratulations you qualify for free shipping' #since it works by checking each elif, it goes to else


print "your order total is", user_order 

#need to create option for shipping to Canada, the prices are different.
#how to repeat the above code but for different values if the user selects Canada.
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give something like

```
user_order < 100.0 > 50.01
```

to python it will evaluate it like this

```
user_order < 100.0 and 100.0 > 50.01
```

But that is not what we want. We want to check this

```
user_order < 100.0 and user_order > 50.01
```

So the correct way to write the conditions will be

```
50.01 < user_order < 100.0
```

**Suggestions:**

1. You dont have to use

   ```
   float(input("how much is your order? "))
   ```

   either

   ```
   float(raw_input("how much is your order? "))
   ```

   or

   ```
   input("how much is your order? ") # Don't use this
   ```

   because `input` will internally do `eval(whatever user inputs)`. That will find the right data type automatically. **Note** Never use `input` in Python2, it can lead to potential security issues. (Thanks Matthias for pointing it out)
2. Whenever you post code (even better, while writing) try and indent the code properly. That will make it easier to debug.

Comment: Using `input` with Python 2 is definitley a bad idea. The internal use of `eval` is not an advantage but a security hole.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks. Forgot to mention that. Now, I included that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean expressions are incorrect; Python chains them naturally, so they must be written that way.

```
 50.01 < user_order < 100.0
```

Comment: Its worth noting that the comparisons in the OPs code are valid, just not doing what they expect. `user_order < 100.0 > 50.01` will be decomposed to `user_order < 100.0 && 100.0 > 50.01` which is equivilent to `user_order < 100.0 && True` Plus given that the python conditions will be interpretted from first to last, even with the expressions being odd, they are still correct.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr `&&` is not a legal operator in python

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the program is repeated twice.  I cleaned it up a touch and this works:

```
user_order = float(input("how much is your order? ")) 
total = user_order

if user_order < 50.00:
    #User would be given price for shipping according to order cost   
    print 'you must pay $6.00 for shipping ' 
    total = user_order + 6.0

elif user_order < 100.0 > 50.01: 
    print 'you must pay $9.00'   #they must pay 9.00 for shipping.
    total = user_order + 9.0

elif user_order < 150.0 > 100.01: #if user order is over 100.01$ but under 150$ 
    print 'you must pay $12.00 for shipping '#12.00$ will be charged for shipping
    total = user_order + 12.0 
else: 
    print 'congratulations you qualify for free shipping'                                
    #this is where the confusion occurs, I need to have the option to ship to US or Canada               
    #the values for shipping to Canada since its different for shipping to that country 

user_ship_area = raw_input('Are you shipping to the US or Canada?')
if user_ship_area != 'US':
    print 'confirmed, we will ship to Canada '

else:
    print "confirmed, we will ship to the United States"

print "your order total is %s"%(total)
```

Comment: Can you explain how you "cleaned it up a touch"?

Comment: The boolean expressions you have are not doing what you expect

Answer (score -1):

this is the correct form, pls notice how to put conditions under if-else in python.

```
user_order = float(input("how much is your order? ")) 

if user_order < 50.00:
    #User would be given price for shipping according to order cost   
    print 'you must pay $6.00 for shipping ' 
    user_order = user_order + 6.0

elif user_order < 100.0 and user_order > 50.01: 
    print 'you must pay $9.00'   #they must pay 9.00 for shipping.
    user_order = user_order + 9.0

elif user_order < 150.0 and user_order > 100.01: #if user order is over 100.01$ but under   150$ 
    print 'you must pay $12.00 for shipping '#12.00$ will be charged for shipping
    user_order = user_order + 12.0 
else: 
    print 'congratulations you qualify for free shipping'                                
#this is where the confusion occurs, I need to have the option to ship to US or Canada               
#the values for shipping to Canada since its different for shipping to that country 

user_ship_area = raw_input('Are you shipping to the US or Canada?')
if user_ship_area != 'US':
    print 'confirmed, we will ship to Canada '

else:
    print "confirmed, we will ship to the United States"
    print "your order total is", user_order 

if user_order < 50.00:
#User would be given price for shipping according to order cost   
    print 'you must pay $8.00 for shipping '
    user_order = user_order + 8.0 

elif user_order < 100.0 and user_order > 50.01: 
    print 'you must pay $12.00' 
    user_order = user_order + 12.0 

elif user_order < 150.0 and user_order > 100.01: 
    print 'you must pay $15.00 for shipping '
    user_order = user_order + 15.0 
else: 
    print 'congratulations you qualify for free shipping' 
#the final output needs to be the user_order + the amount its shipping to depending on   
#the country
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact the logic is repeated twice and is wrong about how python chains boolean operators together.